# If checkbox is checked, change submit input

Tags: jquery

I want that when one or all the checkbox are checked, submit button is not disabled. But if the checkboxes are not checked, then the submit is disabled.

I wrote this code :

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
     if (this.checked) {
         $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
     } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
     }
 });
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  border: none;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

It's almost working but when I uncheck one checkbox, the submit button is already disabled but my others checkboxes are still checked.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that when one or all the checkbox are checked, submit button is not disabled. But if the checkboxes are not checked, then the submit is disabled.

- Use the [`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to select checked checkboxes and then determine whether the length of the returned jQuery object is zero.
- Rather than listening to the `click` even on the checkbox elements, listen to the `change` event.
- You can use the `:checkbox` selector in place of `input[type="checkbox"]`.
- You will also need to replace the `.addClass()` method with the `.toggleClass()` method like below.

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');

$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var atLeastOneChecked = $(':checkbox:checked').length === 0;
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', atLeastOneChecked).toggleClass('disabled', atLeastOneChecked);
});
```

```css
.disabled { background-color: #ececec; border: none; }
input[type="submit"] { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

As a side note, you will need to add some classes to the elements so that not all of the checkboxes in the DOM are selected..

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0){
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled');
    }else {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate function that gets called when your checkbox is clicked, something like this:

```
function toggleSubmit() {
    var boxes = $(':checked');
    var button = $('input[type=submit]');
    if (boxes.length) {
        button.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
    }
}

$(document).on('change', ':checkbox', toggleSubmit);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could do this all in one line, I just made the bool as a variable.  I'd also set the disabled attributes in html initially.

## HTML

```
<input type="submit" disabled class="disabled"/>
```

## jQuery

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    var bool = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',!bool).toggleClass('disabled', !bool);
});
```